# performing calculations in an R list

Tags: r, list

My data comes from a KDB database and is returned as a list.
The list is called `stockdata` and is a list of [8]  --- with [1] being a date [2] being a stock ticker etc and [8] being the mid price of the stock.

I am looking to create `stockdata[[9]]` which is the returns from `stockdata[[8]]` 
in other words even though it isnt a matrix (its returned as a list)   it would look like this

```
[1]       [2]         etc   etc    [8]     [9]
stock     date        etc   etc    100     
stock     date        etc   etc    102     0.02       (ie 2%)
stock     date        etc   etc    104     0.0196     (ie 1.96%)
```

Apologies for the fairly arbitrary question but i am struggling with working with a list - also obviously  there is no first return ie if we have 200 rows we have only 199 returns.

many thanks

Comment: Hey, your explanation of data structure and what you want is not clear to me. Could you post `str(yourdata)`  or for a small example of your data post `dput(yourdata)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `? diff`. So I assume that this is what you are actually looking for in matrix notation:

```
stockdata[ i, 9 ] = (stockdata[ i, 8 ] - stockdata[ i - 1, 8 ]) / stockdata[ i - 1, 8 ]
```

You can easily achieve this by

```
stockdata[[9]] <- c(
  NA,
  diff( stockdata[[8]] ) / stockdata[[8]][ -length( stockdata[[8]] ) ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about turning your list into a dataframe and just calculating the column with vector math:

```
stockdata<-data.frame("stock","blah","blah","blah","blah","blah","blah",seq(100,120,2))
# or stockdata<-data.frame(stockdata) to convert your list
colnames(stockdata)<-paste0("C",1:8)
stockdata$C9<-c(stockdata[1,8],stockdata[1:nrow(stockdata)-1,8])
stockdata$C9<-(stockdata$C8-stockdata$C9)/stockdata$C9
stockdata

C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7  C8         C9
1  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 100 0.00000000
2  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 102 0.02000000
3  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 104 0.01960784
4  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 106 0.01923077
5  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 108 0.01886792
6  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 110 0.01851852
7  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 112 0.01818182
8  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 114 0.01785714
9  stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 116 0.01754386
10 stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 118 0.01724138
11 stock blah blah blah blah blah blah 120 0.01694915
```